# How to solve system of algebraic equations with 9 equations and 19 unknowns?

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic

I have a system of algebraic equations with 9 equations and 19 unknowns. The system is

```
system = {n^4*\[Gamma]*Subscript[A, 0]^4 - n^4*\[Omega]*Subscript[A, 0]^4 + n^4*Subscript[A, 0]^3*Subscript[c, 1] + n^4*Subscript[A, 0]^2*Subscript[c, 2] + 
  n^4*Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[c, 3] + n^4*Subscript[c, 4] - n^4*\[Kappa]^2*Subscript[A, 0]^4*Subscript[\[Alpha], 1] - 
  3*n^4*\[Kappa]^4*Subscript[A, 0]^4*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + n^4*\[Kappa]*Subscript[A, 0]^4*Subscript[\[Beta], 1] + n^4*Subscript[A, 0]^5*Subscript[\[Mu], 1] + 
  n^4*Subscript[A, 0]^6*Subscript[\[Mu], 2] + n^4*Subscript[A, 0]^7*Subscript[\[Mu], 3] + n^4*Subscript[A, 0]^8*Subscript[\[Mu], 4] == 0 && 
4*n^4*\[Gamma]*Subscript[A, 0]^3*Subscript[A, 1] - 4*n^4*\[Omega]*Subscript[A, 0]^3*Subscript[A, 1] + 3*n^4*Subscript[A, 0]^2*Subscript[A, 1]*
   Subscript[c, 1] + 2*n^4*Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]*Subscript[c, 2] + n^4*Subscript[A, 1]*Subscript[c, 3] - 
  4*n^4*\[Kappa]^2*Subscript[A, 0]^3*Subscript[A, 1]*Subscript[\[Alpha], 1] + n^3*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[A, 0]^3*Subscript[A, 1]*Subscript[\[Alpha], 1] - 
  12*n^4*\[Kappa]^4*Subscript[A, 0]^3*Subscript[A, 1]*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 6*n^3*\[Kappa]^2*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[A, 0]^3*Subscript[A, 1]*
   Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + n^3*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[A, 0]^3*Subscript[A, 1]*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 4*n^4*\[Kappa]*Subscript[A, 0]^3*Subscript[A, 1]*
   Subscript[\[Beta], 1] + 5*n^4*Subscript[A, 0]^4*Subscript[A, 1]*Subscript[\[Mu], 1] + 6*n^4*Subscript[A, 0]^5*Subscript[A, 1]*Subscript[\[Mu], 2] + 
  7*n^4*Subscript[A, 0]^6*Subscript[A, 1]*Subscript[\[Mu], 3] + 8*n^4*Subscript[A, 0]^7*Subscript[A, 1]*Subscript[\[Mu], 4] == 0 && 
6*n^4*\[Gamma]*Subscript[A, 0]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^2 - 6*n^4*\[Omega]*Subscript[A, 0]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^2 + 3*n^4*Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^2*
   Subscript[c, 1] + n^4*Subscript[A, 1]^2*Subscript[c, 2] - 3*n^3*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[a, 2]*Subscript[A, 0]^3*Subscript[A, 1]*
   Subscript[\[Alpha], 1] - 6*n^4*\[Kappa]^2*Subscript[A, 0]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^2*Subscript[\[Alpha], 1] + n^2*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[A, 0]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^2*
   Subscript[\[Alpha], 1] + 2*n^3*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[A, 0]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^2*Subscript[\[Alpha], 1] - 
  18*n^3*\[Kappa]^2*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[a, 2]*Subscript[A, 0]^3*Subscript[A, 1]*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] - 
  15*n^3*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]*Subscript[A, 0]^3*Subscript[A, 1]*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] - 18*n^4*\[Kappa]^4*Subscript[A, 0]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^2*
   Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 6*n^2*\[Kappa]^2*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[A, 0]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^2*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 
  12*n^3*\[Kappa]^2*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[A, 0]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^2*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 7*n^2*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[A, 0]^2*
   Subscript[A, 1]^2*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] - 4*n^3*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[A, 0]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^2*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 
  6*n^4*\[Kappa]*Subscript[A, 0]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^2*Subscript[\[Beta], 1] + 10*n^4*Subscript[A, 0]^3*Subscript[A, 1]^2*Subscript[\[Mu], 1] + 
  15*n^4*Subscript[A, 0]^4*Subscript[A, 1]^2*Subscript[\[Mu], 2] + 21*n^4*Subscript[A, 0]^5*Subscript[A, 1]^2*Subscript[\[Mu], 3] + 
  28*n^4*Subscript[A, 0]^6*Subscript[A, 1]^2*Subscript[\[Mu], 4] == 0 && 
4*n^4*\[Gamma]*Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^3 - 4*n^4*\[Omega]*Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^3 + n^4*Subscript[A, 1]^3*Subscript[c, 1] + 
  2*n^3*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[a, 2]^2*Subscript[A, 0]^3*Subscript[A, 1]*Subscript[\[Alpha], 1] - 2*n^2*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[a, 2]*
   Subscript[A, 0]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^2*Subscript[\[Alpha], 1] - 7*n^3*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[a, 2]*Subscript[A, 0]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^2*
   Subscript[\[Alpha], 1] - 4*n^4*\[Kappa]^2*Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^3*Subscript[\[Alpha], 1] + 2*n^2*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^3*
   Subscript[\[Alpha], 1] + n^3*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^3*Subscript[\[Alpha], 1] + 12*n^3*\[Kappa]^2*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[a, 2]^2*
   Subscript[A, 0]^3*Subscript[A, 1]*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 50*n^3*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]^2*Subscript[A, 0]^3*Subscript[A, 1]*
   Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] - 12*n^2*\[Kappa]^2*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[a, 2]*Subscript[A, 0]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^2*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] - 
  42*n^3*\[Kappa]^2*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[a, 2]*Subscript[A, 0]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^2*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] - 
  50*n^2*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]*Subscript[A, 0]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^2*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 
  5*n^3*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]*Subscript[A, 0]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^2*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] - 12*n^4*\[Kappa]^4*Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^3*
   Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 12*n^2*\[Kappa]^2*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^3*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 
  6*n^3*\[Kappa]^2*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^3*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 6*n*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^3*
   Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] - 4*n^2*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^3*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 
  n^3*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^3*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 4*n^4*\[Kappa]*Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^3*Subscript[\[Beta], 1] + 
  10*n^4*Subscript[A, 0]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^3*Subscript[\[Mu], 1] + 20*n^4*Subscript[A, 0]^3*Subscript[A, 1]^3*Subscript[\[Mu], 2] + 
  35*n^4*Subscript[A, 0]^4*Subscript[A, 1]^3*Subscript[\[Mu], 3] + 56*n^4*Subscript[A, 0]^5*Subscript[A, 1]^3*Subscript[\[Mu], 4] == 0 && 
n^4*\[Gamma]*Subscript[A, 1]^4 - n^4*\[Omega]*Subscript[A, 1]^4 + n^2*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[a, 2]^2*Subscript[A, 0]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^2*
   Subscript[\[Alpha], 1] + 5*n^3*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[a, 2]^2*Subscript[A, 0]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^2*Subscript[\[Alpha], 1] - 
  4*n^2*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[a, 2]*Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^3*Subscript[\[Alpha], 1] - 5*n^3*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[a, 2]*
   Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^3*Subscript[\[Alpha], 1] - n^4*\[Kappa]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^4*Subscript[\[Alpha], 1] + 
  n^2*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^4*Subscript[\[Alpha], 1] - 60*n^3*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]^3*Subscript[A, 0]^3*Subscript[A, 1]*
   Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 6*n^2*\[Kappa]^2*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[a, 2]^2*Subscript[A, 0]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^2*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 
  30*n^3*\[Kappa]^2*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[a, 2]^2*Subscript[A, 0]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^2*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 
  115*n^2*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]^2*Subscript[A, 0]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^2*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 
  35*n^3*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]^2*Subscript[A, 0]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^2*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] - 
  24*n^2*\[Kappa]^2*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[a, 2]*Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^3*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] - 
  30*n^3*\[Kappa]^2*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[a, 2]*Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^3*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] - 
  30*n*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]*Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^3*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] - 10*n^2*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]*
   Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^3*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] - 5*n^3*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]*Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^3*
   Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] - 3*n^4*\[Kappa]^4*Subscript[A, 1]^4*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 6*n^2*\[Kappa]^2*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^4*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 
  Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[A, 1]^4*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + n^4*\[Kappa]*Subscript[A, 1]^4*Subscript[\[Beta], 1] + 
  5*n^4*Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^4*Subscript[\[Mu], 1] + 15*n^4*Subscript[A, 0]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^4*Subscript[\[Mu], 2] + 
  35*n^4*Subscript[A, 0]^3*Subscript[A, 1]^4*Subscript[\[Mu], 3] + 70*n^4*Subscript[A, 0]^4*Subscript[A, 1]^4*Subscript[\[Mu], 4] == 0 && 
2*n^2*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[a, 2]^2*Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^3*Subscript[\[Alpha], 1] + 4*n^3*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[a, 2]^2*
   Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^3*Subscript[\[Alpha], 1] - 2*n^2*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[a, 2]*Subscript[A, 1]^4*Subscript[\[Alpha], 1] - 
  n^3*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[a, 2]*Subscript[A, 1]^4*Subscript[\[Alpha], 1] + 24*n^3*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]^4*Subscript[A, 0]^3*
   Subscript[A, 1]*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] - 108*n^2*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]^3*Subscript[A, 0]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^2*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] - 
  72*n^3*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]^3*Subscript[A, 0]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^2*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 
  12*n^2*\[Kappa]^2*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[a, 2]^2*Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^3*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 
  24*n^3*\[Kappa]^2*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[a, 2]^2*Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^3*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 
  54*n*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]^2*Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^3*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 68*n^2*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]^2*
   Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^3*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 28*n^3*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]^2*Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^3*
   Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] - 12*n^2*\[Kappa]^2*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[a, 2]*Subscript[A, 1]^4*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] - 
  6*n^3*\[Kappa]^2*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[a, 2]*Subscript[A, 1]^4*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] - 4*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]*Subscript[A, 1]^4*
   Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] - 6*n*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]*Subscript[A, 1]^4*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] - 4*n^2*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]*
   Subscript[A, 1]^4*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] - n^3*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]*Subscript[A, 1]^4*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 
  n^4*Subscript[A, 1]^5*Subscript[\[Mu], 1] + 6*n^4*Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^5*Subscript[\[Mu], 2] + 
  21*n^4*Subscript[A, 0]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^5*Subscript[\[Mu], 3] + 56*n^4*Subscript[A, 0]^3*Subscript[A, 1]^5*Subscript[\[Mu], 4] == 0 && 
n^2*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[a, 2]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^4*Subscript[\[Alpha], 1] + n^3*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[a, 2]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^4*
   Subscript[\[Alpha], 1] + 36*n^2*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]^4*Subscript[A, 0]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^2*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 
  36*n^3*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]^4*Subscript[A, 0]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^2*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] - 
  42*n*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]^3*Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^3*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] - 90*n^2*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]^3*
   Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^3*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] - 48*n^3*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]^3*Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^3*
   Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 6*n^2*\[Kappa]^2*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[a, 2]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^4*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 
  6*n^3*\[Kappa]^2*Subscript[a, 1]^2*Subscript[a, 2]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^4*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 6*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^4*
   Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 18*n*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^4*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 
  19*n^2*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^4*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 7*n^3*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^4*
   Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + n^4*Subscript[A, 1]^6*Subscript[\[Mu], 2] + 7*n^4*Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^6*Subscript[\[Mu], 3] + 
  28*n^4*Subscript[A, 0]^2*Subscript[A, 1]^6*Subscript[\[Mu], 4] == 0 && 
12*n*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]^4*Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^3*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 36*n^2*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]^4*
   Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^3*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 24*n^3*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]^4*Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^3*
   Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] - 4*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]^3*Subscript[A, 1]^4*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] - 18*n*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]^3*
   Subscript[A, 1]^4*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] - 26*n^2*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]^3*Subscript[A, 1]^4*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] - 
  12*n^3*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]^3*Subscript[A, 1]^4*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + n^4*Subscript[A, 1]^7*Subscript[\[Mu], 3] + 
  8*n^4*Subscript[A, 0]*Subscript[A, 1]^7*Subscript[\[Mu], 4] == 0 && Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]^4*Subscript[A, 1]^4*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 
  6*n*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]^4*Subscript[A, 1]^4*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 11*n^2*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]^4*Subscript[A, 1]^4*
   Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + 6*n^3*Subscript[a, 1]^4*Subscript[a, 2]^4*Subscript[A, 1]^4*Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + n^4*Subscript[A, 1]^8*Subscript[\[Mu], 4] == 0}
```

and unknowns are

```
 unknowns={n, \[Gamma], \[Kappa], \[Omega], Subscript[a, 1], Subscript[a, 2], \
Subscript[A, 0], Subscript[A, 1], Subscript[c, 1], Subscript[c, 2], \
Subscript[c, 3], Subscript[c, 4], Subscript[\[Alpha], 1], Subscript[\
\[Alpha], 2], Subscript[\[Beta], 1], Subscript[\[Mu], 1], Subscript[\
\[Mu], 2], Subscript[\[Mu], 3], Subscript[\[Mu], 4]}
```

I want to solve the system analytically in Mathematica using `Solve` or `Reduce` etc. where `Subscript[A, 1] != 0]`.

```
 Solve[system, Union[{Subscript[A, 0], Subscript[A, 1]}, {\[Gamma], \[Kappa], \[Omega], Subscript[\[Alpha], 1], Subscript[\[Beta], 1], Subscript[a, 1], Subscript[a, 2]}], 
   Assumptions -> Subscript[A, 1] != 0];
```

But, even if I wait 5 hours after evaluating, Mathematica does not give any results.

**Question:** Except the parameter `Subscript[A, 0], Subscript[A, 1]`, there are 17 unknowns. The number of the all subsets of is `2^(17)`. How can we determine the parameters that will be used in the `Solve` in addition to `Subscript[A, 0], Subscript[A, 1]`?

Comment: These equations are highly non-linear. What analytical solution could you possibly expect here? If Mathematica could even give a single solution for one of the unknowns, what could you do? The answer will be pages and pages long.

Comment: I am a Ph.D student and deal with highly nonlinear system of equations and wonder how to develop a viewpoint to get solution sets for cases like this. In `Solve`, when we use several parameters in addition to `A_0,A_1`, I think the obtained solution sets won't be page. (As I see on the other highly nonlinear systems)

Comment: Isn't this art for art's sake?

Comment: `LeafCount[system]` and then `LeafCount[Simplify[system]]` doesn't solve anything but does show it is possible to cut the size by more than half in a few seconds. That might help `Solve` or `Reduce`. Replacing all those `Subscript` with shorter ordinary names might also help. You can put all your `Subscript` back if you get the solution

Comment: I'd suggest that you work your way up. Start with a made-up simpler system of equations -- maybe 2 equations and 3 unknowns with some of the same nonlinearities. If you can solve that, add some more unknowns and equations. This way, you may get an idea of what is feasible.

Comment: I agree with @Bill: `a[0]` instead of `Subscript[A, 0]` every day of the week (but we prefer camelCase to avoid collisions with built-ins like `N`). `Subscript` is a formatting/pretty-printing  tool.

Comment: After eliminating `Subscript`, as repeated urged, you might consider trying `GroebnerBasis` but expect a very long run time.

Answer (score 1):

Determining the parameters to be used in `Solve`, in addition to `{Subscript[A, 0], Subscript[A, 1]}`, as requested at the closing of the question above, is not a trivial task but can be accomplished.  For simplicity, isolate and work with the left sides of the nine equations

```
eq = Simplify[Subtract @@@ List @@ system[[1]]];
```

The first step is to replace `Subscript`, which saves substantial computational time and memory.  A simple approach is

```
map = Thread[Variables[eq] -> Table[Unique["x"], 19]]
eq1 = eq /. map;
(* {n -> x11, γ -> x12, κ -> x13, ω -> x14, Subscript[a, 1] -> x15, 
    Subscript[a, 2] -> x16, Subscript[A, 0] -> x17, Subscript[A, 1] -> x18, 
    Subscript[c, 1] -> x19, Subscript[c, 2] -> x20, Subscript[c, 3] -> x21, 
    Subscript[c, 4] -> x22, Subscript[α, 1] -> x23, Subscript[α, 2] -> x24, 
    Subscript[β, 1] -> x25, Subscript[μ, 1] -> x26, Subscript[μ, 2] -> x27, 
    Subscript[μ, 3] -> x28, Subscript[μ, 4] -> x29} *)
```

Several of the equations contain multiplicative factors of `x18` and `x11`.  Since the question states that `x18 != 0`, multiplicative powers of it can be set to `1`.  Similarly, multiplicative powers of `x11`, which may equal `0`, can be set to `x11`.  These savings are modest, but every bit helps.

```
FactorList /@ eq1;
DeleteCases[%, {x18, _}, 4] /. {x11, _Integer} -> {x11, 1};
eq2 = (Times @@ Power @@@ #) & /@ %
```

Examination of eq2 (which is rather long to reproduce here) indicates that 13 variables enter linearly.

```
linvar = {x12, x14, x19, x20, x21, x22, x23, x24, x25, x26, x27, x28, x29};
```

which can be demonstrated by

```
CoefficientArrays[eq2, linvar]
```

[image]

```
mat = % // Last // Normal;
FreeQ[mat, Alternatives @@ linvar]
(* True*)
```

Solving directly for any nine `linvar` variables is straightforward, if the corresponding matrix has rank 9; i.e., the corresponding determinant does not vanish.

```
f[v_] := Module[{rank}, 
    rank = CoefficientArrays[eq2, v] // Last // Normal // MatrixRank; 
    If[rank == 9, v, Nothing]]
f /@ Subsets[linvar, {9}]
```

115 nine-element subsets of `linvar` meet this requirement.  For instance,

```
Solve[Thread[eq2 == 0], {x12, x19, x20, x21, x22, x23, x24, x26, x28}]
```

produces results in terms of the remaining ten variables in just a few seconds.  However, the OP requested solutions for `x17` and `x18`, which do not enter the equations linearly.  The approach I took was to `Solve` seven of the nine equations in `eq2` for variables from `linvar` and substitute the results into the remaining two equations to obtain two polynomial expressions for `x17` and `x18`.  Because they have fewest terms, the remaining two are selected as `eq[[8;]]`.  They can be further simplified by

```
eq3 = ReplacePart[eq2, 8 -> Collect[eq2[[8]] - 8 x17 eq2[[9]], 
   {x24, x28, x29}, Simplify]]
```

where `{x24, x28, x29}` are the remaining `linvar` variables in those two equations.  To find an additional four `linvar` variables, I proceeded as above.

```
g[v_] := Module[{rank}, 
    rank = CoefficientArrays[eq2[[;; 7]], Join[v, {x24, x28, x29}]] 
    // Last // Normal // MatrixRank; If[rank == 7, v, Nothing]]
 g /@ Subsets[Complement[linvar, {x24, x28, x29}], {4}]
```

which yields 140 possibilities.  Choose

```
Solve[Thread[eq3[[;; 7]] == 0], {x23, x24, x25, x26, x27, x28, x29}] // Flatten;
Numerator /@ Together /@ (eq3[[8 ;;]] /. %);
Last /@ FactorList /@ %;
eq4 = Collect[% /. {z_, 1} -> z, {x18, x17}, Simplify]
```

Once again, the two new equations contain multiplicative factors that do not yield useful results.  So, I removed them.  Here are the two equations in final form.

```
{2 (2 + 9 x11 - 41 x11^2 + 30 x11^3) x16^3 x17^6 x19 + 
     4 (4 + 20 x11 - 71 x11^2 + 30 x11^3) x16^3 x17^5 x20 + 
     14 (2 + 13 x11 - 37 x11^2) x16^3 x17^4 x21 - 
     16 x11 (-14 + 31 x11 + 30 x11^2) x16^3 x17^3 x22 + 
 x18^3 ((-10 + 81 x11 - 173 x11^2 + 102 x11^3) x17^3 x19 + (-20 + 
     152 x11 - 275 x11^2 + 102 x11^3) x17^2 x20 + 
     7 x11 (2 + 17 x11 - 39 x11^2) x17 x21 + 
     4 (20 - 88 x11 + 195 x11^2 - 162 x11^3) x22) + 
 x18^2 (4 (-4 + 45 x11 - 107 x11^2 + 
     66 x11^3) x16 x17^4 x19 + (-52 + 496 x11 - 967 x11^2 + 
     366 x11^3) x16 x17^3 x20 - 
     7 (10 - 79 x11 + 85 x11^2 + 66 x11^3) x16 x17^2 x21 + 
     4 (12 - 92 x11 + 391 x11^2 - 510 x11^3) x16 x17 x22) + 
 x18 ((-2 + 117 x11 - 337 x11^2 + 222 x11^3) x16^2 x17^5 x19 + 
     8 (-2 + 53 x11 - 122 x11^2 + 48 x11^3) x16^2 x17^4 x20 - 
     7 (10 - 115 x11 + 187 x11^2 + 24 x11^3) x16^2 x17^3 x21 - 
     16 (14 - 49 x11 + 15 x11^2 + 108 x11^3) x16^2 x17^2 x22), 
 (1 + 6 x11 - 25 x11^2 + 18 x11^3) x16^3 x17^6 x19 + 
     2 (2 + 13 x11 - 43 x11^2 + 18 x11^3) x16^3 x17^5 x20 + (7 + 
     56 x11 - 149 x11^2 - 6 x11^3) x16^3 x17^4 x21 - 
     56 x11 (-1 + 2 x11 + 3 x11^2) x16^3 x17^3 x22 + 
 x18^3 (3 (-1 + 8 x11 - 17 x11^2 + 10 x11^3) x17^3 x19 + 
     3 (-2 + 15 x11 - 27 x11^2 + 10 x11^3) x17^2 x20 + (1 - 3 x11 + 
     50 x11^2 - 90 x11^3) x17 x21 - 
     14 (-2 + 9 x11 - 19 x11^2 + 15 x11^3) x22) + 
 x18^2 ((-5 + 54 x11 - 127 x11^2 + 78 x11^3) x16 x17^4 x19 + 
     2 (-8 + 74 x11 - 143 x11^2 + 54 x11^3) x16 x17^3 x20 - (19 - 
     148 x11 + 139 x11^2 + 162 x11^3) x16 x17^2 x21 + 
     14 (2 - 13 x11 + 42 x11^2 - 48 x11^3) x16 x17 x22) + 
 x18 ((-1 + 36 x11 - 101 x11^2 + 66 x11^3) x16^2 x17^5 x19 + 
     3 (-2 + 43 x11 - 97 x11^2 + 38 x11^3) x16^2 x17^4 x20 - 
     3 (7 - 77 x11 + 120 x11^2 + 24 x11^3) x16^2 x17^3 x21 - 
     28 (2 - 6 x11 - 2 x11^2 + 21 x11^3) x16^2 x17^2 x22)}
```

The order of these two polynomials are third in `x18` and sixth in `x17`, as can be seen from

```
Dimensions[CoefficientList[eq4, x18]]
(* {2, 4} *)
Dimensions[CoefficientList[eq4, x17]]
(* {2, 7} *)
```

The straightforward attempt to `Solve` them with

```
Solve[Thread[eq4 == 0], {x17,x18}]
```

ran for some 18 hours without result.  (Simplified problems I attempted to solve with `Reduce` and `GroebnerBasis` also failed to produce results in a reasonable amount of time.)  Nonetheless, Mathematica can solve these equations without difficulty, if given some assistance.  Define

```
tmplt = Thread[Flatten[{{a0, a1, a2, a3}, {b0, b1, b2, b3}}] -> 
    Flatten[CoefficientList[eq4, x18]]]
```

The `eq4` can be represented by

```
eqab = {a3 z^3 + a2 z^2 + a1 z + a0 == 0, b3 z^3 + b2 z^2 + b1 z + b0 == 0}
```

where `z` is used instead of `x18` for brevity.  Applying `Eliminate` then gives

```
Subtract @@ Eliminate[{a3 z^3 + a2 z^2 + a1 z + a0 == 0, 
    b3 z^3 + b2 z^2 + b1 z + b0 == 0}, z] // Simplify
(* a0^3 b3^3 - a0^2 (b3 (-a2 b2^2 + 2 a2 b1 b3 + a1 b2 b3) + 
   a3 (b2^3 - 3 b1 b2 b3 + 3 b0 b3^2)) - 
   b0 (a3^3 b0^2 + a3^2 (-a2 b0 b1 + a1 (b1^2 - 2 b0 b2)) + 
   b3 (-a2^3 b0 + a1 a2^2 b1 - a1^2 a2 b2 + a1^3 b3) + 
   a3 (a2^2 b0 b2 + a1 a2 (-b1 b2 + 3 b0 b3) + a1^2 (b2^2 - 2 b1 b3))) + 
   a0 (a3^2 (b1^3 - 3 b0 b1 b2 + 3 b0^2 b3) + 
   b3 (a2^2 (b1^2 - 2 b0 b2) + a1^2 b1 b3 + a1 a2 (-b1 b2 + 3 b0 b3)) + 
   a3 (a2 (-b1^2 b2 + 2 b0 b2^2 + b0 b1 b3) + a1 (b1 b2^2 - 2 b1^2 b3 - b0 b2 b3))) *)
```

In other words, the two equations can be solved only if the consistency condition just given equals 0.  Now, inserting values for the a and b parameters yields

```
FactorList[% /. tmplt][[-2 ;;]];
eq5 = Times @@ Power @@@ %;
Length[CoefficientList[eq5, x17]]
(* 12 *)
```

Only the last two of the 17 factors lead to solutions of interest.

```
Solve[%% == 0, x17] // Flatten
```

The solutions, `Sqrt` and `Root` functions, are far too lengthy to reproduce here.  With `x17` now evaluated, `x18` can be obtained in principle by substituting each of the eleven solutions for `x17` in turn into either of `eq5` and solving the resulting cubic equations.  I emphasize that the results presented in this answer merely are sample results. The original set of equations has hundreds, perhaps thousands of distinct solutions, because it is underdetermined and also nonlinear in some variables.